# Converting IIS rewrite rule to Apache

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, iis, url-rewriting, proxy

So I'm having trouble converting this rewrite rule in IIS to Apache. Works well in IIS but not at all in apache.

Original IIS rewrite rule:

```
<rule
 enabled="true"
 stopProcessing="true"
 name="Route API calls to test server”>
 <match url="(api/.*)" />
 <action type="Rewrite" url="http://api.testdomain.com/{R:1}" />
</rule>
```

Apache rule that I'm trying out:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^api/(.*)$ http://api.testdomain.com/$1 [P]
```

Comment: you're trying to proxy this request, or just redirect/rewrite to the new url?

Comment: proxy.  Think I have it figured out though.  Answering below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So looks like I wasn't honoring the original pod in the original rule that carries the '/api' with the request.  Modified rule below works like a charm now (though I've hardcoded the '/api' portion of the path, but same results).

Original IIS rewrite rule:

```
    <rule
    enabled="true"
    stopProcessing="true"
    name="Route API calls to test server”>
    <match url="(api/.*)" />
    <action type="Rewrite" url="http://api.testdomain.com/{R:1}" />
    </rule>
```

Apache rule

```
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule ^/api/(.*)$ http://api.testdomain.com/api/$1 [P]
```